# on click reward videos link nothing happens?

Tags: android, admob

I have admob reward videos in my app.
The problem is, when I click in the textview to show the ad, nothing happens.

```
public RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;




MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917");

    // Use an activity context to get the rewarded video instance.
    mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
    mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(this);



tip.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    loadRewardedVideo();
            }
        });
```

and the overrides...

```
 @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded() {
        System.out.println("Loaded()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened() {
        System.out.println("Opened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoStarted() {
        System.out.println("Started");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed() {
        System.out.println("Closed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem) {
        System.out.println("reward");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication() {
        System.out.println("left");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
        System.out.println("failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onRewardedVideoCompleted() {

    }


    private void loadRewardedVideo() {
            mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd("ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/5224354917",
                    new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        }
```

did I miss something? what is wrong here?
thanks.

---

output

```
I/Ads: This request is sent from a test device.
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1654K, 22% free 7281K/9236K, paused 9ms, total 10ms
I/Ads: SDK version: afma-sdk-a-v15000000.15000000.0
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1478K, 27% free 6773K/9236K, paused 8ms, total 8ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1109K, 25% free 6979K/9236K, paused 10ms, total 11ms
D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xb7aa9b10: ver 2 0
E/EGL_emulation: tid 1994: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
W/HardwareRenderer: Backbuffer cannot be preserved
W/AwContents: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
I/ExoPlayerImpl: Init ExoPlayerLib/2.4.2 [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, unknown, 19]
I/chromium: [INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(56)] Async pixel transfers not supported
D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 589824
D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 98304
D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 98304
D/MetadataUtil: Skipped unknown metadata entry: gsst
    Skipped unknown metadata entry: gstd
D/MediaCodecVideoRenderer: FalseCheck [legacyFrameSize, 640x360] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, unknown, 19]
    FalseCheck [legacyFrameSize, 640x360] [generic_x86, Android SDK built for x86, unknown, 19]
I/OMXClient: Using client-side OMX mux.
I/SoftAAC2: Reconfiguring decoder: 0->44100 Hz, 0->2 channels
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1284K, 25% free 6998K/9236K, paused 16ms, total 16ms
I/System.out: Loaded()
```

I also tested in a real device, and nothing happens too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was also trying to search the reason for the same problem after successfully running reward ads on my app for nearly 1.5 years. Even my account got blocked, but nobody told me that the earlier rewardad library is completely revamped.

The following steps may only work for the applications on Play Store.

There is a new reward Ad library and a new way of implementing it. Google has brought rewardAds under the inAppBilling library completely separating it from Admobs. You can only see its earnings there. You have to implement it through Play console.

- Goto Play Console>Your Application>Store Presence>Rewarded Products
- Accept the agreement for the first time.
- Create any product just like you create any other inapp purchase product here.
- Keep in mind the product created as a reward product also has skutype.INAPP and must be consumed.
- Initiate your billing library and query purchases as usual including your reward product id as consumable products.
- To load the ad simply use the following in queryPurchases and enable your button(as I used visibility for View vidbut)

`for (SkuDetails skuDetails : skuDetailsList) {
                        if (skuDetails.isRewarded()) {
                            rewardSkuDetails = skuDetails;
                            billingManager.queryRewardAsync(skuDetails, new RewardResponseListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onRewardResponse(BillingResult billingResult) {
                                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
                                        findViewById(R.id.vidbut).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        // Enable the reward product, or make
                                        // any necessary updates to the UI.
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }`

- To show the ad simply initiate the purchase flow like

  billingManager.initiatePurchaseFlow(rewardSkuDetails, null, BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);

If you need more help with setting up billingManager you can freely ask in comment.
I hope it will help you in implementing the new RewardAds. Goodluck!

Comment: oh, thank you very much! I'd never guess something like this... I'll try it! thank you friend!